# Real parallelism in Linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, parallel-processing

I am trying to have real parallelism on Linux shell, but I can't achieve it.

I have two programs. Allones, that only prints '1' character, and allzeros, that only prints 0 characters.

When I execute "./allones & ./allzeros &", I get big prints of '0's, and big prints of '1's, that mix in big chunks (e.g. 1111....111000...0000111...111000...000"). My processor has 8 cores.

However, when I executed my own program on a multi-core FPGA (with no OS), (If I distribute programs on different cores) I get something like "011000101000011010...".

How can I run it on Linux to get a result similar to what I get on a multi-core FPGA?

Comment: maybe `stdbuf -o0 /allones & stdbuf -o0 /allzeros &` Will help. Note, not all systems have `stdbuf`, so if not available, check for `unbuffer`. Also as we don't have your program available to test with, you may only need the first `stdbuf`. OR you can include your code, and tag your Q for that language. There may be other functions in your lang. that avoid buffered output (which is almost certainly your issue here). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: My program is very similar to the one that is proposed below by that other guy (i.e. spam.c).

Comment: I tried stdbuf -o0 also, and that also fixed the problem. Therefore, I can either use stdbuf -o0 or use fflush(stdout) in my program.
It was interesting, since on my "light real time OS" that I had on my FPGA, I didn't experience this buffering effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're experiencing libc's default line buffering:

Here's a test program `spam.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  while(1) {
    printf("%s", argv[1]);
  }
}
```

We can run it with:

```
$ ./spam 0 & ./spam 1 & sleep 1; killall spam
```

> 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111(...)000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000(...)

On my systems, each block is exactly 1024 bytes long, strongly hinting at a buffering issue.

Here's the same code with a `fflush` to prevent buffering:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  while(1) {
    printf("%s", argv[1]);
    fflush(stdout);
  }
}
```

This is the new output:

> 100111001100110011001100110011001100110011100111001110011011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100011000110001100110001100100110011001100111001101100110011001100110011001100110000000000110010011000110011